# Stop .replace() from replacing same string if found within a word

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex, replace

For example: There is a page that lists some items with colours. Some are listed as Nav some are listed as Navy.

```
$('.ProductDetails a').each(function() {
    var text = $(this).text();
    $(this).text(text.replace("Nav", "Navy")); 
});
```

Will result in all 'Nav' being changed to Navy - great!

But it will also result in 'Navy' being changed to Navyy. (i.e. it replaces the 'nav' in navy to navy and leaving the 'y' after the 'nav' has been replaced)

Is there a way to stop this using the technique above or will I have to change the script to account for these double ups.

My current solution is to add a space after Nav  `$(this).text(text.replace("Nav ", "Navy"));`

But this isn't ideal because some of the items may have a / after them and no space.

Comment: Without some actual text samples (more than 1), its a little hard to determine a solution. Its nice to throw in language jargon, but it does not help without samples.

Comment: As you say, `Nav` is just an example.

Comment: Well it's any string that could be contained in another word.

It's not hard to make up examples:
Replacing dog with cat will also result in the word dogma being replaced as catma. 

Replacing colour with peanut would result in colourblind being peanutblind

etc

Comment: So regex knows about language. Do you think regex knows what a word is? What would get replaced in `Lincoln _Nav_igator`? How would you replace abbreviations or contractions. The list is endless. Where does a word start, end, etc

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
$('.ProductDetails a').each(function() {
    var text = $(this).text();
    $(this).text(text.replace(/^Nav$/g, "Navy")); 
});
```

Or:

```
    $(this).text(text.replace(/\sNav\s/g, "Navy"));
```

Or:

```
    $(this).text(text.replace(/\bNav\b/g, "Navy"));
```

*There are many other ways...*

**Note that you can use this `text` overload:**

```
$('.ProductDetails a').text(function(index, old) {
    return old.replace(/\sNav\s/g, "Navy");
});​
```

Comment: Or, using the overload that takes a function reference: `$(this).text(function(old) { return old.replace(/^Nav$/g, "Navy"); });`

Comment: This won't replace something like "Nav." Maybe not important in this case, but good to be aware of.

Comment: @AndrewWhitaker. +1.Thanks for the note, but it can be even better, see the update.

Comment: @gdoron: Ah, nice, I completely forgot we were inside of an `.each` :O

Comment: `text` overload has `(index, old)` as arguments ;)

Comment: @VisioN. You again... :) thanks, I copied it without looking too much.

Answer (score 1):

you can use a regex replace like this:

```
$(this).text(text.replace(/\snav[\s/]/g,"navy");
```

means:

```
replace [whitespace]nav[whitespace or "/"] to "navy"
```

Answer (score 1):

You want to use a regular expression that is aware of word boundaries:

```
text.replace(/\bnav\b/, 'Navy')
```